# CMD or Powershell command to combine (merge) lines from two non-equal files

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am a novice for scripting. Let me give an example of what I want to achieve.
The two files go like this:

File 1: (FYI: I do not know how many such lines would come up!)

GROUP 1
GROUP 2
GROUP 3
GROUP 4
....
..
GROUP n

File 2 : (FYI: I do not know how many such lines would come up!)

BODY 1
BODY 2
..
.
BODY n

Desired Output : Since the lines in file 1 will be always greater than lines in file 2. I want the file 2 lines to repeat themselves from start whenever they run out, but start their second run from where the first run ended; and loop till all lines in file 1 are done.

GROUP 1 BODY 1
GROUP 2 BODY 2
GROUP 3 BODY 1
GROUP 4 BODY 2
....
..
GROUP n BODY n

This is a very intensive task, and I have about 10000 such line to merge.
Note that the number of lines will always be an even to even ratio.
If there are 10 lines in File 2, then there might be 100 lines in file 1 (not 103 etc)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that StackOverflow is not a code factory. What have you tried yourself sofar?

Comment: $f1 = Get-Content file1
$f2 = Get-Content file2

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $f1.Length; ++$i) {
  $f1[$i] + "`t" + $f2[$i]
}        I have this code, but it only works when the number of lines are equal in both files, my file is unequal

Comment: Add that to the question. See also: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$f2 = Get-Content .\file2.txt               # Load all lines of file 2 into memory
$i = 0                                      # Initiate an index for file 2
Get-Content .\file1.txt | Foreach-Object {  # Pipe each line of file 1 into the for each loop
    if ($i -ge $f2.Count) { $i = 0 }        # Reset the index if it exceeds the line count of file 2
    $_, $f2[$i] -Join ' '                   # Join the lines and drop the result in the pipeline
    $i++                                    # Increase the index
} | Set-Content .\output.txt                # Save each line in .\output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @iRon, It worked for files for 10 entries. I am hoping it will do its magic when I get the files with 10000 lines